# Who're the people Agent Sitwell lists to Captain America

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

In Captain America: Winter Soldier, Agent Sitwell reveals that:

> Project Insight has been compromised,  and now aims to take out anyone Hydra deem a threat.

He then gives a list of people that might/will be targeted.

The scene happened too fast for me to reflect all the names, but I think they mentioned:

> Steven Strange, and T'Challa

But what is the full list of people mentioned?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sitwell specifically mentions six people. T'Challa was not one of the ones listed in the movie.

> "Zola's algorithm is a program...for choosing Insight's targets!"
>
> "What targets?"
>
> "**You! A TV anchor in Cairo, the Undersecretary of Defense, a high school valedictorian in Iowa City. Bruce Banner, Stephen Strange,** anyone who's a threat to HYDRA! Now, or in the future."

Comment: My bad. I have no idea who they are besides Banner and Strange.

Comment: No worries. It's pretty quick and easy to mishear. I know a lot of people swear they heard Tony Stark mentioned. There's been some speculation as to who the TV anchor and valedictorian are. I'll see if I can dig it up for you.

Comment: He never said Stark, as you show, but you could see his picture when they were taking aim.

Comment: @phantom42 did we ever get an idea of who they are?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage nothing concrete or official that I've ever heard. The speculation was that the anchor was referring to Moon Knight, which sort of fits since he's a tv producer in the comics, but I've never seen any valedictorian theory that worked at all.

Answer (score 1):

The TV Anchor in Cairo is most likely Moon Knight, and the highschool valedictorian is probably Ethan Edwards, a superman knockoff. Of course, this doesn't mean we'll *see* Ethan, but it is a nice reference.